# How to use Windows API Code Pack?

Tags: c#, winapi, aero-glass

I would like to make my application transparent with the aero glass, i looked around on internet, and i cant seem to find any info on how to use the AeroGlass Demo code. 
So i compiled the DLL files

> Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll

and

> Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll

and referenced them in my project, yet still cant seem to use the code that is in

> Samples/AeroGlass/CS/WindowsFormsGlassDemo/Form1.cs

Code from Form1.cs: http://pastebin.com/t0kymfLb

Does anyone have any idea on how to use the code?

Comment: You will need to share your code so we can see what you have tried and therefore comment helpfully.

Comment: @user1793036 I dont have code, as i cant get it to work.. I copied code from the example, also put the nessesary using directives, but still some messages like "are you missing a using reference?"

Comment: You already have the sample code, so all you need is to spend time analyzing the source files, project settings and so on. If you don't even see which are the references used in the sample projects, you won't get your own working.

Comment: Hard to diagnose cause for errors if you won't give details of your code and the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got aeroglass to work without windowsapicodepack.